# Fs.writeFile callback not called

Tags: node.js, callback, fs

Node version: 8.11.2

I have a simple CSV export function that takes an array of objects, and generates the headers of the file based on the object properties of the objects.

```
const exportCsv = (list, fileName) => {
  if (list.length > 0) {
    let headers = Object.keys(list[0]);
    let opts = { headers };
    let parser = new Parser(opts);
    let csv = parser.parse(list);
    fs.writeFile(`./output/${fileName}.csv`, csv, err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log(`Wrote ${fileName} to disk.`);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('List is Empty. Nothing to export.');
  }
};
```

It was working great, but now the call back in the `fs.writeFile` call isn't firing, and there are no errors or exceptions from VS Code's Debugger.

What would cause it to nut run?

Comment: I've temporarily fixed the issue by writing a synchronous version with `fs.writeFileSync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If process is dead before the writing path is done, your callback will not be called because it is an asynchronous.

So you have 3 options

1. make sure your process is not dead before writing path is done (you can use async/await or promise)
2. use `writeFileSync` instead (less effective but less confusing)